# Visual studio debugger is slow / terminates when expanding watch on a container/list etc

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio, c#

I'm afraid to say I can't figure this one out, but my VS2008 appears sick. Any time I navigate to a particular view in my app, VS will hold for roughly 60 seconds on "Symbol loading Windows/.../***.dll" but then will navigate as normal BACK to that view.

Additionally, if there is ever a watch on a container or list and that watch is expanded, VS will timeout and terminate the debugging session.

Can anybody help me with what I might doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you installed service pack 1 ? This problem happens to me as well, but not frequently so i dont know how to resolve it correctly. Its worst when i use the remote debugger.

I have noticed that lists in the watch cause the most problems. I usually debug using tracepoints to print out the value of variables instead of breakpoints when i need to view variables. Its due to the nature of my application which sufferes timeout if i breakpoint.

I have visual studio 2005 installed on my computer and i get this problem as well, but its incredibly rare on visual studio 2005.